# how to configure two or more hosts on WAS server

Tags: websphere-7, coexistence

I have the application deployed on WAS. Now i have made few changes on the code and want to deploy on WAS . I want the old deployment to work as it is. But i also want the new changes to be deployed and work separately independent of the other without affecting. How to make both exist simultaneously on WAS.
Is there a way please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to configure two or more hosts on websphere server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34348947/how-to-configure-two-or-more-hosts-on-websphere-server)

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying there is nothing shared between the applications, they are completely separate?
Have you tried using a different context root and application name?
From a webcontainer perspective, if the context_root is different, it should be treated as a completely different application and should accomplish this.

If it doesn't work after that, the link below discusses various issues you may run into and how to deal with them.

IBM WebSphere Developer Technical Journal: Co-hosting multiple versions of J2EE applications
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0405_poddar/0405_poddar.html